# Multiple Condition in Excel files

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck with this table...

```
  A  B  C  D E
1 y     y    Orange
```

I would like to have the result in the Column E:

```
If A and C =y than = Orange
```

Thanks,

Steve V.

Comment: Would you only ever have two times a "Y" per row? And would it always be one of these 4 combinations?

Comment: You are making a typical beginner's mistake: `If A and C =y than = Orange` makes no sense working with a computer, it should be `If A=y and C=y than =Orange`.

Comment: You haven't used AND once in your formula. You are also missing commas and the else at the end.  Any time you need to build a nested formula, build each part separately. When they all work, put them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

=IF(AND(A1="y",C1="y")," Orange",IF(AND(A1="y",D1="y"),"Blue",IF(AND(B1="y", D1="y"),"Red", IF(AND(B1="y",C1="y"),"Black",**IF nothing applies**))

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed it works.
Just one question, if one line can be blue , black and orange at the same time, how can I handle that on the condition ?

Comment: It goes from left to right, so if the first condition does not match, it goes to the second. If you would have four y on the first line, it will say Orange because this is the first match. If you change the order of the IF statements, you will have different results.

Comment: When I have more than 2 "y" orange come first !
Should I use condition OR ? if I would like to have 2 oucomes on the results?

Comment: You can only have one outcome in a cell. What do you exactly try to achieve? 

If you want to see combinations, I would use columns E,F, G and H. All have only one if formula.
column E: =IF(AND(A1="y",C1="y")," Orange","") 
Column F: =IF(AND(A1="y",D1="y"),"Blue","")
etc

then in column I you can make a combination of the four columns
for row one cell I1 = E1&" "&F1&" "&G1&" "&H1
This will combine the four columns in one cell with spaces in between.